# Wireless network management

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, adsl-router

My (wireless) network implementation, goes like this :

5 ADSL lines (Up to 24 Mbps) but they work aprox. @ 4-5 Mbps.

I want to support 60 clients on the same time.

The routers we have available : ZTE ZXHN H108NS -> Annex A(PSTN)

I was wandering what is the best practice i should follow in order to avoid big downtimes.

The default firmware (according to my knowledge) cannot restrict torrents, nor monitor the network usage.

Also, i am balancing my load by splitting the lines into different lines.

```
C1,C2...C12 -> Line 1
C13 ... C24 -> Line 2
C25 ... C36 -> Line 3
C37 ... C48 -> Line 4
C49 ... C60 -> Line 5
```

At least one client in Line 1 and one in Line 2 with bad behaviour could cause me 24 dissapointed clients.

Comment: Yeap, i know that i will have big downtimes, but i want to minimize that time, so i would like some tips like how to block torrents or monitor the activity, blocking irrelevant websites etc.

Comment: Because 5 ADSL lines for 60 people is too much, and i don't believe that they will follow any kind of rules :(

Comment: If at least one of them has enabled some torrent or windows update or something big, he will destroy the whole line.

Comment: As i said on my 2nd line, the lines are actually working on 4-5 Mbps, for aprox 12 clients each. The WiFi, i think is irrelevant but i thought i should mention that also.